# Laravel 5.1 file upload error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm struggling with Laravel 5.1 LTS's requests. Every time I upload a file, I get the file name from `$request->input('input_file')`, but

`$request->hasFile('input_file')` is false and

`$request->file('input_file')` is null.

**Frontend**

 `{!! \Form::input('file','input_file',null,['style'=>'display:none;']) !!}`

which translates to

`<input type="file" name="input_file" id="input_file" style="display:none;">`

[image]

Comment: show your full code, form code

Comment: Paste `{!! Form:open()` !!} code. Let's see what is there ?

Comment: do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` element.

If you're using Laravel Collective's Form/Html package, you can pass `'files' => true` to the array:

```
{!! Form::open(['files' => true]); !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `'files'=>'true'`

Try this,

```
Form::open(array('url' => '/uploadfile','files'=>'true'));
```